# How to log into a website using webbrowser control and username & password stored in variables

Tags: c#, authentication, browser

I want to be able to log into a website via C# webbrowser without any user input.
I want to get the username and password from local variables.

I hope someone can help me.

Please give clear C# code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the login-page of the site, expose the `<form></form>` that does the login, mimic the form with a `POST` request and encode the username/password in the body of the POST.

To fabricate this, you'll probably have to make a custom request. Linking up the session ID of the Request & the web-browser will probably be tricky, you'd have to set the referral url manually in the next post, and migrate the cookies the server told you to set.

---

The other solution is to inject some javascript into the login page that populates the fields and hits the submit button.

Either way it's pretty page-specific.